# How to get access to the PromiseResult in React when calling Azure Cosmos DB api

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to pull some rows from a Cosmos DB and then map through them to display a component for each.  All of the documentation I can find for the Azure Cosmos DB API logs rows to the console one by one but I can't find one then tells you how to return the whole string.

I'm new to this so am probably doing it horribly wrong but I am now stuck and cannot move on.  Hope you can help ...

In my App.js I have this

```
function App() {
const [newMembers, setNewMembers] = useState(dataFetch());
```

In my dataFetch.js I have

```
export default async function dataFetch() {
  const { endpoint, key, databaseId, containerId } = config;
  const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, key });
  const database = client.database(databaseId);
  const container = database.container(containerId);

  // Make sure Tasks database is already setup. If not, create it.
  // await dbContext.create(client, databaseId, containerId);

  try {
    console.log(`Querying container: Items`);

    // query to return all items
    const querySpec = {
      query: "SELECT * from c",
    };

    // read all items in the Items container
    const { resources: items } = await container.items
      .query(querySpec)
      .fetchAll();
    return items;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
}
```

When I console.log the result back it says

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Array(3)
0: {id: '154', forename: 'Fred', surname: 'Robson', address1: 'Some address', address2: 'Kingsmead', …}
1: {id: '416', forename: 'Lee', surname: 'Robson', address1: 'Some address', address2: 'Kingsmead', …}
2: {id: '900', forename: 'Kathryn', surname: 'Robson', address1: 'Some address', address2: 'Kingsmead', …}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

I saw something elsewhere about using .then but when I tried

```
const { resources: items } = await container.items
  .query(querySpec)
  .fetchAll()
  .then(() => {
    return items;
  });
```

It said "dataFetch.js:33 Cannot access 'items' before initialization"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing in the first two code blocks is perfectly fine. However with putting the result of `dataFetch()` into the `newMembers` state, you're just storing the promise in there which just get's resolved at some point and you can retrieve the results at any point with `newMembers.then(actualResult => ...)`.

However, I think you would rather like to keep the actual members array in the `newMembers` state. This can be done by e.g.:

```js
function App() {
    const [newMembers, setNewMembers] = useState([]); // initially set to an empty array

    useEffect(() => {
        dataFetch().then(members => setMembers(members));
    }, []); // providing an empty array means: run this effect only once when this component is created.

    // do something with the newMembers. Initially, it will be [] 
    // but as soon as the data is retrieved from the DB, the actual data will be 
    // in the state and the component will be rerendered.
}
```